# How to find the earlier date between two events?

Tags: hiveql, hue

I have the following table:

[image]

For each member from this table, I would like to get the event date. The event date should be pulled by comparing the event dates for "run" and 'jog" events and which ever date is smaller/earlier, that date is what i need.

So my output table will look like:

[image]

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz : Can you help?

Comment: @Ramesh Yelda-  can help?

Comment: OR @leftjoin - anyone can help?

Comment: Please replace the picture with text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming event_date is of date type or at least a string in YYYY-MM-DD format (and it was changed in the Excel)

```
select      member
           ,min(event_date)
from        mytable
where       event in ('run','jog')
group by    member
```